# What is best way to parse not separated (invalid) json string?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to parse some json response into php array, the problem is nginx push stream module response with not separated json string, is possible to parse this without using regex?

```
'{"id":1,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}{"id":2,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}{"id":2,"channel":"1","text":{"key_x": "value_x"}}'
```

**Edit**

The real issue was that nginx push-stream module send archive in stream, so thats why there is no separator between json data in my snippet.

Comment: `json_decode` ?

Comment: json_decode return null

Comment: the string you provided is invalid json, so .... yes, `json_decode` is unlikely to return anything.

Comment: yes, as i said, looking for some solution.

Comment: encode properly on the sending side ... show the code for that if you want any help. Also, you should change the title to 'How to parse invalid json'

Comment: I can't change pushstream module source, that is default response for stored messages

Comment: `$json = '[' . str_replace('}{', '},{', $json) . ']';` if you want a very quick and dirty solution, note that it's not guaranteed to work if there are any strings that contain the text `}{`. And stop using anything that returns data like this, it's a very bad sign.

Comment: @Sojtin : check this, https://3v4l.org/isBkD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '{"id":1,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}{"id":2,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}{"id":2,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}';

$str = str_replace('}{', '},{', $str);
$str = '[' . $str . ']';

print_r(json_decode($str));
```

https://3v4l.org/BNVTg

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is actually possible without either changing the output or use regex / str_replace.

If you have control over the output you should change the output to valid json:

```
{"data":[
    {"id":1,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"},
    {"id":2,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"},
    {"id":2,"channel":"1","text":"Hello World!"}
]}
```

It you cant do this then you could try to use str_replace with explode:

```
$data = str_replace('}{', '}<should_be_absolut_unique>{');
foreach( explode('<should_be_absolut_unique>', $data) as $json ){
    # json_decode($json)
}
```

This is of course very unsave and not guaranteed to work because you dont know if the string replace works correctly if you do not know the data that is send!

Comment: OP mentioned in comments that he cant change the source of the data.